# Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 70

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I am trying to launch an iOS app with Appium on Simulator.

Appium : Version 1.17.1

Xcode : Version 1.14

Mac : 10.15.5

Simulator: iPhone Pro

iOS Version: 13.0

When I start my automation test, I get this error in few moments:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild
>   failure: xcodebuild failed with code 70   xcodebuild error message:
>   (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)   UnknownError: An unknown
>   server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
>   error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure:
>   xcodebuild failed with code 70

Any idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.
Check whether an instance of simulator is targeting a different iOS version.